# Unsubscribe from a specific queue after a given Date in RabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I have a Java class that -upon a certain action from the GUI- initiates a connection with the RabbitMQ server (using the pub/sub patter) and listens for new events.

I want to add a new feature where I will allow the user to set an "end time" that will stop my application from listening to new events (stop consuming from the queue without closing it).

I tried to utilise the basicCancel method, but I can't find a way to make it work for a predefined date. 
Would it be a good idea to initiate a new thread inside my Subscribe class that will call the basicCancel upon reaching the given date or is there a better way to do that?

**Listen to new events**

```
    private void listenToEvents(String queueName) {
        try {
              logger.info(" [*] Waiting for events. Subscribed to : " + queueName);

              Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {

                  @Override
                  public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope,
                                             AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws IOException {

                    TypeOfEvent event = null;

                    String message = new String(body);


                    // process the payload
                    InteractionEventManager eventManager = new InteractionEventManager();
                    event = eventManager.toCoreMonitorFormatObject(message);


                    if(event!=null){    
                        String latestEventOpnName = event.getType().getOperationMessage().getOperationName();

                        if(latestEventOpnName.equals("END_OF_PERIOD"))
                            event.getMessageArgs().getContext().setTimestamp(++latestEventTimeStamp);            

                        latestEventTimeStamp = event.getMessageArgs().getContext().getTimestamp();                                    
                        ndaec.receiveTypeOfEventObject(event);                  
                    }
                  }
                };

                channel.basicConsume(queueName, true, consumer);   
             //Should I add the basicCancel here?
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("The Monitor could not reach the EventBus. " +e.toString());
        }     

    }
```

**Initiate Connection**

```
  public String initiateConnection(Timestamp endTime) {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        try {
            props.load(new FileInputStream(everestHome+ "/monitoring-system/rabbit.properties"));
         }catch(IOException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
        }                       

        RabbitConfigure config = new RabbitConfigure(props,props.getProperty("queuName").trim());

        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();

        exchangeTopic = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String exchangeMerged = config.getExchange();
        logger.info("Exchange=" + exchangeMerged);
        String[] couples = exchangeMerged.split(";");

        for(String couple : couples)
        {
            String[] infos = couple.split(":");
            if (infos.length == 2)
            {
                exchangeTopic.put(infos[0], infos[1]);
            }
            else
            {
                logger.error("Invalid Exchange Detail: " + couple);
            }
        }

        for(Entry<String, String> entry : exchangeTopic.entrySet()) {

            String exchange = entry.getKey();
            String topic = entry.getValue();

            factory.setHost(config.getHost());
            factory.setPort(Integer.parseInt(config.getPort()));
            factory.setUsername(config.getUsername());
            factory.setPassword(config.getPassword());

            try {
                connection1= factory.newConnection();
                channel = connection1.createChannel();
                channel.exchangeDeclare(exchange, EXCHANGE_TYPE);
                /*Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                args.put("x-expires", endTime.getTime());*/
                channel.queueDeclare(config.getQueue(),false,false,false,null);
                channel.queueBind(config.getQueue(),exchange,topic);            
                logger.info("Connected to RabbitMQ.\n Exchange: " + exchange + " Topic: " + topic +"\n Queue Name is: "+ config.getQueue());
                return config.getQueue();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a delayed queue, setting the time-to-leave so the message you push there will be dead-lettered exactly as soon as you want to stop your consumer.

Then you have to bind the dead letter exchange to a queue whose consumer will stop the other one as soon as it gets the message.

Never use threads when you have RabbitMq, you can do a lot of interesting stuff with delayed messages!